# Install for dual boot fails on grub update

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have an openSUSE install (best support for my hardware at this time) with space set aside for Kubuntu (best support for photogrammetry software at this time).

Partion setup is efi boot partition 500MB as sda1, userspace 1.5TB formatted as XFS on sda2, large volume 320GB on sda3 with volumes swap 20GB, opensuse 250GB, formatted as btrfs, and the balance reserved for kubuntu. Nothing's encrypted.

I run the installer, choose the manual partitioner, tell it to format the 50GB volume as ext4 and mount as /, specify sda1 for boot loader, and continue. Right at the end of the process, it tells me it failed to install bootloader.

Boot back into openSUSE, go to bootloader configuration, specify probe foreign OS. Reboot now shows grub entry for ubintu, but when I click on it, it says no such device and load kernel first.

Any ideas what's going on? I'll update after next try with exact wording on the error message.

EDIT: It's "The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot." 
Same with ubuntu or kubuntu, secure boot or legacy support.

I've tried sda and sda1, and I even tried the same partition where the OS will live on the theory that I could find and move it. I think the OS is actually installed, but the automated tool in openSUSE failed to configure GRUB correctly. Any idea how to do that manually?

Comment: Is openSUSE in UEFI boot mode? If so you must have an ESP - efi system partition. And for any install in UEFI mode it must have an ESP. You do not install boot loader to partition, but to a drive like sda or sdb, not sdas12. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Thaks oldfred for your interest in my issue. Yes, openSUSE is UEFI. I tried to follow the instruction at the site you linked, attempting to add repo throws ERROR: '~yannubuntu'  user or team does not exist. If you're on that team, I'm sorry you had to hear it from me.

Comment: Feeling stupid, wifi wasn't connected. Report's at paste.ubuntu.com/p/c9TMb2kcjd

Comment: Do not know LVM. But it does not look like Ubuntu fully installed. Script shows no UEFI boot entry, no grub boot stanza and no fstab to see what is to be mounted. Did you try a BIOS install, not UEFI? You do show Secure Boot on, but kernels for Ubuntu are not the signed one's for UEFI Secure Boot.

Comment: Yes, I tried legacy support both enabled and disabled.  I'm doing this for a friend and he gets the computer tomorrow, after a long drive on my part, so we're pretty much at the end of the window now, but thanks again, oldfred.